# Find closest item from ALS model using KNN

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system, pyspark

I have a dataset like:

```
cid_int   item_id   score
  1         678      0.5
  2         787      0.6
  3         908      0.1
  .          .        .
  .          .        .
```

Now I'm running ALS model on this pyspark dataframe for getting recommendation using Collaborative Filtering.

```
als = ALS(userCol= "cid_int", itemCol= "item_id", ratingCol= "score", rank=5, maxIter=10, seed=0)
model = als.fit(X_train)
```

Now I have question that what does output of `model.userFactors` returns, does it return item embeddings like for m items I'll get all the embeddings?

And if yes can I use `KNN` on these embedding to find the closest items to given item?